# Matrix with arrows and comments

Tags: tikz-pgf

> Sending out the bat signal

Can you help me to draw this matrix along with the arrows and the comments?

[image]

> MWE:

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 & \\
 &
 \begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |  c |  }


\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
$u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|} 
$u_{2}$ & 4 &  & 3 & 1 &  &   & 3  &   \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|} 
$u_{3}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
$u_{4}$ & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
$u_{5}$ & 3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
$u_{6}$ & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ \hhline{~*8{|-}|}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest `matrix` in TikZ for better access to anchors. With TikZ, you can use the

```
('matrix name'-'row num'-'col num')
```

syntax to access anchors of the cells and thus facilitate drawing/filling.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
  \centering 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
      nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
      nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
              & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5    &  6  & 7 & 8 \\ 
      $u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ 
      $u_{3}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ 
      $u_{4}$ & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ 
      $u_{5}$ & 3 &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 3 & &  0 \\ 
      $u_{6}$ & & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & 2 &  & 4 &  &\color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \\ 
    };
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \fill[orange!30](m-2-5.north west)rectangle(m-6-5.south east);
      \fill[gray!30](m-2-6.north west)rectangle(m-6-6.south east);
      \fill[orange!30](m-4-2.north west)rectangle(m-4-9.south east);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[-latex](m-4-9.east)--+(1,0)node[above right]{User-based similarity measure}|-(m-3-9.east);
    \node[left]at(m-4-1.west){Active User};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks great! Is there any way to label the columns as well?

Comment: @NaveganTeX: Do you mean by adding a first row?

Comment: Just like `u_{1}` but in the case of colums it would be `i_{1}` I don’t know if by adding an extra row you can add the label, maybe you can

Comment: @NaveganTeX: Yes, simply adding a first row would do. See my update.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I’ll get back to you if I cannot draw the other similarity ;)